# How to remove a widget from tree

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to be able to remove a widget from tree, or remove a child of a widget. I tried to use states to change a widget to null but it's returning an error. Is there a solution ?
Here is the error
https://gist.github.com/litekangel/e2037cf5dc4dbd9c0c0a9860ad3b0270

I finally found a solution to hide/remove a widget : I just replaced it by an empty widget (may be I will add a small animation) but I am still looking for a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: "it's returning an error" isn't much information ;-) Please show the code that allows to reproduce the problem and the exact error message(s) you get.
What about just not adding it in `build()`?

Comment: I added it in my previous post, but I think it's normal that it's refuses to create widget with null as one its children.

Answer (score 8):

In flutter you don't really update a tree of widget you actually generate a new tree every time you need to change it. So you only have to change the returned value of your widget `build` function.

Answer (score 6):

If you want an empty widget, `Container()` is a good choice.

Comment: `const SizedBox.shrink()` is allegedly even better.

Comment: perfect! i used this work perfectly. here is my code example to remove widget 
    scanned == totalScan ? const SizedBox.shrink() : ElevatedButton(...),

Answer (score 5):

**Another good approach to replace widgets in the tree is to give your widgets a `key`.**

(Flutter will rebuild the subtree if the key changes.)

So let's say you have a StreamBuilder, and for, whatever reason, need the child widget to be built from scratch every time, you can do this:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: bloc.myDependencyChanged, // A hypothetical bloc which notifies when a relevant dependency has changed.
  builder: (_, snap) {
    final dep = MyChangingDependency();
    // MyWidget will NOT get reused by flutter if the key changes.
    return MyWidget(dep, key: ValueKey(dep.getId()));
  },
);
```